# Python- Runtime error(NZEC)

Tags: python-3.x, runtime-error, eof

**Question-**

https://www.codechef.com/problems/SINS

**Compiler used-**

https://www.codechef.com/ide

**Input method-**

Custom input of codechef compiler.

**My attempt-**

```
T=int(input())
def fnc(a,b):
    if b!=0:
        return fnc(b,a%b)
    else:
        return int(a*2)
while T>0:
    X,Y=map(int,input().split())
    if X==0:
        print(Y)
    elif Y==0:
        print(X)
    elif X==Y:
        print(X*2)
    else:
        f=fnc(X,Y)
        print(f)
    T=T-1
```

**Issue:**

I am getting the following runtime error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "./prog.py", line 8, in <module>
 EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

The output is correct but still there is this runtime error.

Comment: That is because the `input()` is getting End Of File.  You need to trap the `EOFError` exception.

Comment: @cdrake what do you mean?

Comment: Try `print(T)` and see what input triggers the error.

Comment: How are you providing it with input?

Comment: Using custom input of codechef compiler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the `input()` is getting End Of File (I assume you are using Python 3). You need to trap the `EOFError` exception and break out of the loop when you get it.  You asked what I meant by that comment, this is what I mean:

```
try:
    X, Y = map(int, input().split())
except EOFError:
    break
```

Comment: How come I am getting EOFError? Is it because there is no further input?

Comment: @suyashsingh234: you did not answer the question "how are you providing the input?" .  The input stream, known as `stdin`, is by default the keyboard but could be redirected from a file.  At some point the data stream is exhausted which raises EOF.  We don't normally see that in python, it is just that you have chosen to use `input()` and a strange  IDE.

Comment: @suyashsingh234: so it is custom input from the IDE you are using, but what I would need to know to answer correctly is *exactly* how that is connecting to `stdin`.  It is really a question for your supplier of the IDE.